# IntelliJ says build failed and through Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashset

The project shows zero errors at compile time but when it starts to execute during build it crashes and says:

[image: Build Output]

```
Module project_name production java.lang.NullPointerException: null elements are not allowed in THashSet
```

But the same project start working properly when I change its directory from D to C drive. Why this happen I'm unable to solve. Please help!

After comment this code it starts working and after disabling comment with no change in code it also works fine.

```
// if main db not loaded
if (!Get_db_path.Main_not_found && Db_Connect.conn == null) {
    Sel_db.connect();  // selected database
    Sel_db_error();
}   // display error
Main_db_error(Get_db_path.Main_not_found);

GetToggleStatus();
```

Comment: Please provide more details and code. We can't just look at the most generic exception in the world and figure out how you got this error

Comment: You are right but believe me only above line that a mention is a source of error. The project contains more than 10 java classes and all are error free that's why they are not there. The same project is executing properly when it is moved to other drive.

Comment: there's a difference between Checked Exceptions and Runtime Exceptions. Somewhere in your code, there's an Object or field that's null depending while running on the drive you use. Without more code snippets, there's no way of telling where the error's at, besides the fact that it has something to do with your THashSet

Comment: Please review question. I haven't use hashSets

Comment: Some times it happens due to disk errors try disk defrag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened suddenly to me at compile time when running the `main` method.
I solved it in **Intellj** by just rebuilding the project.

--> Go to the **Build** menu and click on **Rebuild Project**.

Next time you run the `main` method it should just work again.

---

<sub>Btw: I had this problem in another context: writing to `ByteArrayOutputStream` with `PrintWriter`.</sub>